# What is the difference between Asc() and AscW()?

Tags: vb.net

What is the difference between `Asc` and `AscW` in vb.net?
I have similar question about `Chr()` and `ChrW()` functions too!
Is there any benefits for using them with or without `W` suffix?!

Comment: This is the kind of things which should be searched in internet before asking: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/us-en/library/zew1e4wc(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: @varocarbas That's your vision of view! Every question can be googled or maybe answered by reading a full documentation guide or spending some time! Stackoverflow is a Q&A community to provide answers for any question which may be searched again by someone else for making "problems solved / questions answered" much faster! My question is not outfitting any rules [described here](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Bear in mind that I didn't down-vote your question nor voted to close it (I never said that it goes against the rules). The whole point of my comment was highlighting that perhaps next time you might prefer to do a quick web search (much easier than posting a question in SO, dealing with all the answerers/commentators, bearing the downvotes, etc.) before.

Comment: @varocarbas Finally what you did is that you put an answer as a negative comment to get comment votes for yourself and downvotes for question! 2 upvotes for your comment and 2 downvotes for question! maybe more and more later! You're not helping SO or making it better!

Comment: "To get votes for yourself?!" Do you know how SO works? Getting upvotes in comments is almost completely irrelevant! Not sure what you are saying next, but your ideas seem to be quite mixed up. Anyway... I am currently starting my new SO-participation (have been inactive for quite a long time), where I solve this kind of (misunderstanding) problems in the following way: this is the last time I will talk to you.

Comment: @varocarbas Best Idea! For you and for bulldozers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unicode is a standard that is designed to replace the ANSI standard for encoding characters in a numeric form. Because the ANSI standard only uses a single byte to represent each character, it is limited to a maximum of 256 different characters. While this is sufficient for the needs of an English speaking audience, it falls short when the worldwide software market is considered. With the Unicode standard, each character is represented by two bytes, so that the entire Unicode character set includes 65,536 possible locations.

Microsoft Windows NT, Microsoft Windows 2000, and Microsoft OLE 2.0 are entirely Unicode based, and Visual Basic (4.0 and higher) represents all strings internally in Unicode format. The AscW and ChrW functions allow access to the full range of Unicode characters. **These functions work in the same way as the original Asc and Chr functions except that they support arguments from 0 to 65,535 instead of just from 0 to 255**. Many Visual Basic objects (such as the debug window and the label and text box) return a "?" when these objects do not know how to display an Unicode character.

Please read more [**here**](https://jeffpar.github.io/kbarchive/kb/145/Q145745/) about this (it's the official article from Microsoft; their link is now dead)

Comment: That link is now dead

Comment: @HackSlash updated link, yes they do go dead after some time; thanks for the info!